# How to create a function for a command that processes concurrently

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, discord, discord.py

When I type the command `!sleeper` into the discord, then immediately after type `!hello`. The bot is basically on pause for 10 seconds because it is processing `!sleeper`. After the 10 seconds it sends the message `I have been sleeping for 10 seconds` and then immediately after `Hello partner!`. How can I make it so the entire bot is not "paused" if someone sends the `!sleeper` command.

What's happening now:

1. I type `!sleeper`
2. I Type `!hello`
3. Bot waits 9-10 seconds
4. Bot sends `I have been sleeping for 10 seconds`
5. Bot sends `Hello partner!`

What I want:

1. I type `!sleeper`
2. I Type `!hello`
3. Bot sends `Hello partner!`
4. Bot waits 9-10 seconds
5. Bot sends `I have been sleeping for 10 seconds`

PS: I wrote "waits 9-10 seconds" because it takes me about a second to type `!hello`

```
import time

from discord.ext import commands


class Hello(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.__class__.__name__} Cog is ready')

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hello partner!')

    @commands.command()
    async def sleeper(self, ctx):
        await self.sleep_now()
        await ctx.send('I have been sleeping for 10 seconds')

    async def sleep_now(self):
        time.sleep(10)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Hello(client))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment on Kyle's answer, you want to process a function asynchronously.

Then what you want to implement is a thread. You can create a thread and sleep 10 seconds inside the thread (or do your time expensive task) and then print 'i have been sleeping for 10 seconds'. Therefore it would not block the execution of !hello and other commands. It would look something like this

This would be the function of the expensive task

```
async def thread_function(ctx):
    time.sleep(10)
    await ctx.send('I have been sleeping for 10 seconds')
```

and this would be how you would be calling it

```
 x = threading.Thread(target= thread_function, args=(ctx))
```

---

Alternatively, you could use an event loop, which is a bit more advanced topic. You can research it if you want, but what it essentially does is that it evaluates the function you called in runtime and executes it independently without creating a new thread. I strongly to encourage you to check it out.
Nevertheless, here is what its could could look like

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, thread_function, ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using background tasks to achieve this. I'm not sure if this is the best or cleanest solution but you can find more documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html).

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


class Hello(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        # flag variable to keep track of if we are waiting for a response from sleeper
        self.sleeping = 0

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.__class__.__name__} Cog is ready')

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hello partner!')

    @commands.command()
    async def sleeper(self, ctx):
        # if the task is already running, ie. someone already called sleeper
        # you cannot start a background task if it is already running, it will cause an error
        if self.sleep.is_running():
            await ctx.send('Already sleeping!')
        else:
            # start the background task
            self.sleep.start(ctx)

    # The loop runs 2 times
    # It runs immediately when you start the task (when you type !sleeper) and then again in increments of the time specified
    # I use a flag to check when to send the message and cancel the task (after the first ten seconds)
    # cancelling the task stops it from sending additional messages every ten seconds
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
    async def sleep(self, ctx):
        # helper method to stop the background task right after it sends the message
        async def stop_sleep():
            self.sleep.cancel()
        # checks to see if the task is sleeping or not
        if self.sleeping == 1:
            # reset the value
            self.sleeping = 0
            # send the message
            await ctx.send('I have been sleeping for 10 seconds')
            # stop the task
            await stop_sleep()
        else:
            # keep track of it sleeping
            self.sleeping = 1


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Hello(client))
```

## Edit:

There is a *much* better way to solve your problem without using background tasks. Use asyncio instead of time to sleep.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

class Hello(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.__class__.__name__} Cog is ready')

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hello partner!')

    @commands.command()
    async def sleeper(self, ctx):
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await ctx.send('I have been sleeping for 10 seconds')
```

Comment: The tasks is not what I am looking for. The `sleep_now()` function is to represent a helper non-discord function that takes a while to process. So essentially, how do I make a custom function that can be called within a command function and remain concurrent. So yes, I can use `await asyncio.sleep(10)`, but what if I have a custom process that takes 10 seconds? Imagine the `sleep_now()` wasn't really a sleeping function, but rather a process that takes a while to finish